# t-test module issue python

Tags: python, pandas, stat

I am working with t-test on a pandas dataframe.
I have about 40 attributes and one target variable.

I am using this piece of code for t-test analysis:

```
stats.ttest_ind(df[df['target']==1]['variable'], df[df['target']==0]['variable'])
```

I have imported the necessary modules as well:

```
from scipy import stats
```

However, I keep getting this error, and am not sure what am I doing wrong:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-187-dbb554ef9ddf> in <module>()
----> 1 stats.ttest_ind(df[df['target']==1]['variable'], 
df[df['target']==0]['variable'])

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ttest_ind'
```

Can anyone suggest some solution for this, I have been working on this issue for hours and don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

ttest_ind(df[df['target']==1]['variable'], df[df['target']==0]['variable'])
```

Is there a function called stats in your code?

```
def stats(x):
    print(x)

stats.ttest_ind()
```

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ttest_ind'

Comment: Thank you this worked, I don't know what caused this issue because it originally worked. But once again, thank you